# I installed gnome-control-center from command line. It is saying 'Unable to init: could not connect: connection refused'

Tags: gnome-control-center

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10. I installed gnome-control-center from command line.  It is saying 'Unable to init: could not connect: connection refused' . Wanted to change the colors of text and background of bash console from command line

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to change the colour preferences for WSL to something more readable, you can do it all in Windows like this:

0. Start your WSL shell (if it's not already running)
1. Right-click title bar of the shell and select "Properties"
2. A dialog will appear, and you will need to:

   1. Select "Screen Text"
   2. Select the box that is the colour you would like to change
   3. Set the RGB value of the box to something that is better for you
   4. Press [OK]

Following these steps will change the colour in the console palette to something much more readable.

***Note:** If you use vim, you will need to change those colours separately. [This answer on U&L explains exactly how to do it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88880)*.

Hope this gives you what you need